# Kubernetes deployment not exposed

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml

For some reason, this specific deployment does not expose its service to the outside world. I'm pretty sure my syntax is ok since I use a similar set of files for a deployment only using TCP. I suspect having both TCP and UDP is kind of causing a problem. What's weird is if I run manually the docker in one of the worker, it works:

```
 docker run -p 27015:27015 -p 27015:27015/udp -e STEAM_ACCOUNT_TOKEN=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX grido/csgo-edge
```

Service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: csgo200
spec:
  selector:
    app: csgo200
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: udpcsgo1
    port: 27015
    protocol: UDP
  - name: tcpcsgo1
    port: 27015
    protocol: TCP
```

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use 
apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: csgo200
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: csgo200
  replicas: 1 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: csgo200
    spec:
  containers:
  - name: csgo200
    image: grido/csgo-edge
    ports:
    - name: tcpcsgo200
      containerPort: 27015
      protocol: TCP
    - name: udpcsgo200
      containerPort: 27015
      protocol: UDP
    env:
    - name: STEAM_ACCOUNT_TOKEN
      value: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

[root@master ~]# kubectl describe svc csgo200

```
Name:                     csgo200
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
{"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata": 
{"annotations":{},"name":"csgo200","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports": 
[{"name":"udpcsgo...
Selector:                 app=csgo200
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.97.122.32
Port:                     udpcsgo1  27015/UDP
TargetPort:               27015/UDP
NodePort:                 udpcsgo1  31314/UDP
Endpoints:                192.168.1.37:27015
Port:                     tcpcsgo1  27015/TCP
TargetPort:               27015/TCP
NodePort:                 tcpcsgo1  31314/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.1.37:27015
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: Could you please provide output of `kubectl describe svc csgo200`

Comment: Service type should be LoadBalancer instead of NodePort.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think the type should be loadbalancer as I don't want/nor need one for this use case. Plus, the loadbalancer does not support mix protocols which is needed here.

Comment: output of kubectl describe added in main question.

Comment: It’s listening on the `NodePort:` port (31314 in your output) on every node.

Answer (score 1):

Your service type is declared as `NodePort` which makes your service available on your nodes. Check [service types](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types), I would recommend to use LoadBalancer type

Comment: only nodeport supports both tcp & udp as far as I can tell:    https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/30253

Comment: @MathieuDuperré the status of that PR is `merged`, as far as I can see, there is no problem for kubernetes dealing with UDP. If you still want to use NodePort, check what is the TargetPort used, and make sure that there is no firewall on your node on that Port